# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused When Command in "Controller" But Words Normally in Tinker

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

So I have trying to make Autocomplete in my Project (Dictionary), and the SQL Worked normally if testing SQL Command using #Tinker.

```
# php artisan tinker

Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.1.19 — cli)
>>> use App\WordsList;
>>> WordsList::where('Translation', 'english')->first();
=> App\WordsList {#2962
     ID: 4,
     Word: "اَلْإِنْكِلِيزِيَّة",
     SimpleWords: "الإنكليزية",
     Translation: "english",
     Views: null,
   }
>>>
```

but if make that in AutoComplete Controller like this:

```
    public function search(Request $request) 
    {
          $search = $request->get('term');

          $result = WordsList::where('Translation', 'LIKE', '%'. $search. '%')->first();

          return response()->json($result);

    }
```

Web file (Routes)

```
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AutoCompleteController@search');
```

if found this problem:

```php
## (URL) http://127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete/?term=english

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `WordsList` where `Translation` LIKE %english% limit 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me on several occasions.  More often than not, it is helpful to take a look at your `.env` file.

Look at the `DB_HOST` key.  If it is currently `127.0.0.1`, try changing the value to `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a simple problem with your database connection. I don't know your environment (vagrant homestead/ virtual mashine/ etc.).

First you should check your database configuration. Have a look at these article:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused#best-reply-117961

Your db-host should be set to **localhost** and your port should be **3306**.

Try to clear and cache your config again with `php artisan config:cache`.

At least you could try to debug your code and check the `DB::connection()` / `DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()`